# Working with Language Characters in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

wonder if anyone can help - I thought I had solved this but i still have some problems.

Basically people are inputting information into a CMS system I have inherited, from varying countries.

After a bit of help and research I have got it at least saving into the DB correctly. eg ó saves as ó.

However when retrieved from the DB it still says Ã³. Is there a way I can convert this to the ó on the php page, why would this not show correctly ?

I used mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link2);  and set names in the setup file just after the connection, and the php pages in question seem to have to the correct meta of utf8, the pages are set to transistional in the header.

I have worked out by using the mb detect encoding that the php page is displaying the character in ascii.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question but good background reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read through

Comment: Ok I have narrowed things down to characters like ó are insteredt correctly from the CMS pages, and I can see them correctly in phpmyadmin, however when pulling these characters back in on the page they show as Ã³ etc.

Comment: could you write URL of this page? maybe it's other problem, HTTP headers or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column's charset is utf-8, use the BINARY keyword when SELECTing:

```
SELECT BINARY utf8_column, ...
```

This will guarantee that the utf-8 data will not get converted in the way to the browser because PHP itself is encoding unaware and treats strings as stream of bytes.

---

And this is the custom function I use instead of `htmlentities` that works well with utf-8 data:

```
function xmlEntities( $s ) {
    return str_replace( array( '&', '"', '<', '>' ),
                        array( '&amp;', '&quot;', '&lt;', '&gt;' ), $s );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - just came across a line which when I took it out - fixed the issue $otherFields[$rowFields["name"]] = htmlentities( $rowFields["value"] ); Bascially it's the htmlentities that's messing up the utf8. What I'm worried about it just taking these out, as it seems these lines are all over the files on the site ( inherited this). Is there a way to preserve that htmlenetities and preserve the utf8 ?

Comment: @mro Look into htmlentities documentation, it has an ability to set encodings: `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');`. But if all your project is in utf8 then you can use `htmlspecialchars` instead, then you will not need to set encodings.

Comment: @nobody Your methods should work, but this is not correct way to manage encoding problems. MySQL and PHP has a bunch of tools for this :)

Comment: @Karolis What do you mean manage? You want to print utf-8 data from a source that is utf-8 itself through a language that is encoding unaware, the best method is the one that avoids any conversion. To me this is the best method.

Comment: @nobody Neither MySQL, nor PHP does any charset conversion if an application has right configuration. You are doing this in hackish style. This is not a good practice.

Comment: Hi - many thanks - adding utf-8 into the html entities has solved it !

Comment: @Karolis I usually try to write code that works on as many servers without the need to change their configuration or the code, maybe I have this habit because of the field that I work in.

Comment: @nobody I mean not server configuration, but application configuration in the code. For instance instead of selecting BINARY you can set the correct charset at the connection time and then don't worry about the query at all. Such queries becomes cross-database compatible. Also I see no point to use xmlEntities, when htmlspecialchars does the same thing :)

Comment: @Karolis we can argue about these things all day which is something we are supposed not to do here in comments.